# Apple II: LED near joystick connector?

Tags: apple-ii

Some Apple II motherboards have a red LED in the back-right corner near the joystick / cassette in/out connectors. I have never seen it illuminated. What is its purpose?

Answer (score 7):

This is the self-test LED. Here's a quote from Sather's excellent [Understanding the Apple IIe](https://archive.org/details/Understanding_the_Apple_IIe).

> There is an LED (Light Emitting Diode) connected across the speaker
>   jack on the Apple IIe motherboard. However, the LED (CR2) does not
>   normally light because there is not enough voltage developed across
>   the speaker primary to cause visible light emission. The light does
>   glow when SPKR is toggling with the speaker disconnected. You can see
>   this for yourself by disconnecting the speaker plug and holding open
>   Apple and close Apple and pressing CONTROL-RESET. This causes firmware
>   diagnostic execution with speaker tones or light emission from the
>   LED when the speaker is disconnected. The LED thus provides a means of
>   verifying diagnostic performance on a motherboard with no speaker
>   connected.